# Django Mezzanine Templates

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm considering Django Mezzanine for a project. Normally I'd do it in pure Django. The only thing that stops me is the Template. I'm not a front end developer, I use templates from wrapbootsrap. I'm wondering if I will still be able to use bootstrap templates with Mezzanine... or is there a conflict somewhere? Any comment will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mezzanine](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine) is integrated with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) so you could just add the elements from the Bootstrap documentation that you want and it will work fine in the templates.